# Login with additonal condition laravel 5.3

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3

I am trying to authenticate a user with the obvious email and password and also if the ban_status is set to 0 in the database.

I have had a look at the newest laravel docs and I have tried it this way in the AuthenticateUsers.php

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required', 'password' => 'required', 'ban_status' => '0',
    ]);
}
```

This does not do anything as far as I can tell and will log in the user regardless whether there ban status is 0 or not, where should I be doing this extra condition?

Thanks

Comment: Try 'ban_status' => 'required|in:0',

Comment: Doesn't log in at all now, I'm not sure where the issue is

Comment: Maybe you could try: ban_status' => 'required|boolean:0

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required', //????
                             'password' => 'required', 
                             'ban_status' => '0',
    ]);
```

- I'm not sure why you have 'required' there by itself, so I was thinking something along the lines of this:

  ```
  $user = $this->username();
  $this->validate($request, [
      $this->username() => 'email' =>    'bail|required|email|exists:dbnamehere.tablenamehere|min:7', //can also be username
                           'password' => 'bail|required|min:8',                                  
                           'ban_status' => ['required',
                                             Rule::unique('users_table_name_here')->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
                                                    $query->where(['account_id',$user],
                                                                  ['ban_status', 0])]
                                             }) 
  ]);
  ```

This may not work right off so you might have to tinker with it a little bit but it makes nice use of Laravel's Eloquent models. So hopefully this points you in the right direction. Also be sure to change table names and field names to whats in your database.

Happy Coding =)

**Reference:**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation